# How to optimize the following code so as to run it faster?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, optimization, python-3.7

First of all, I have a pandas dataframe with the following columns:
"YEAR","1DIGIT","2DIGITS","3DIGITS","SIZE","CODE","VALUE" with 1.8 million rows.
Here is my code to correct the data I have:

```
for year in list(data.YEAR.unique()):
    data1 = data[data.YEAR == year]
        for dig in list(data1.3DIGITS.unique()):
            data2 = data1[data1.3DIGITS == dig]
            for size in list(data2.SIZE.unique()):
                data3 = data2[data2.SIZE == size]
                data.loc[(data.YEAR == year)&(data.3DIGITS == dig)&(data.CODE == 9122),"VALUE") = data3[data3.CODE.isin(9001,9057)].VALUE.sum()
```

As you can see I want to sum values of codes 9001 and 9057 and assign it to value of code 9122. This works but really slow, it takes almost 1 and half an hour. Is there anything we can do to make it faster?

Comment: This might be more suited for codereview

Comment: can u give a simple example

Answer (score 2):

Try using [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function of pandas.

This would look something like:

```
def add_col(df):
    df.loc[(df.CODE == 9122),"VALUE") = df[df.CODE.isin(9001,9057)].VALUE.sum()
    return df

data.groupby(['YEAR', '3DIGITS', 'SIZE']).apply(add_col)
```

Comment: I cannot use groupby because using it makes the data unusable.

Comment: Can you please explain me better why you cannot use my solution?

Comment: When I group by YEAR, 3DIGITS and SIZE, VALUEs are summed because there are lots of VALUEs belonging a YEAR, 3DIGITS and SIZE triple.